# Exit recursion early with a value?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
public static double AskForNums(int i, double max = 0)
    {     

        if (i <= 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input value for number " + i);
            double input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (input > max)
            {
                max = input;

            }

            AskForNums(i + 1, max);

        }           

        return max;
    }
```

I'm trying to ask for 12 inputs and return the highest value. At the last recursion `max` contains the highest vallue. However, it then goes through 12 times again in reverse (recursion) and ultimately leaving me with the first value.

My cousin's homework was to ask user input for 12 numbers and print the highest number and he wasn't allowed to use loops or arrays.

I then started wondering if looping is possible without the provided loops (for/while etc).

**QUESTION** Is it possible to retain a value from the peak part of recursion? Any code I try is redudant as the `max` variable gets changed through every level of recursion. Is there a way to exit early with value?

Comment: Hint: you're ignoring the return value from your recursive call, which makes it pointless. Ask yourself what you might want to do with the returned value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably really want to do something like this:

```
public static double AskForNums()
{
    return AskForNums(1, 0.0);
}

private static double AskForNums(int i, double max)
{
    if (i <= 12)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input value for number " + i);
        double input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (input > max)
        {
            max = input;
        }

        max = AskForNums(i + 1, max);
    }
    return max;
}
```

The `public static double AskForNums()` method is to get the ball rolling, but the `private static double AskForNums(int i, double max)` is used to keep track of the `max` as the code runs.

Note that you need to set `max` in the line `max = AskForNums(i + 1, max);` to keep track of the best `max` value in the recursion.

And there's no point exiting early as you never know if the `max` value is the last one entered.